# Relations - One to many in Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, relational-database

Data Structure in Parse Server:

**Objects** - objectId:String, userPointer:Pointer, title:String, image:File, description:String, verified:Bool, comments:Relations (relations so that when I click on the comments class it loads associated comments)

**Comments** - objectId:String, userPointer:Pointer, imagePointer:Pointer, comment:String

I am trying to save a comment to the comments class.
At the same time I need to add the Relation to the Objects Class
 ............with the aim being that when you query the relation, you get all of the comments associated with it.

so far I've tried:

```
// Create the comment
    let myComment = PFObject(className:"Comments")
    myComment["comment"] = "kgvhgv"


    // Add a relation between the Post and Comment
    myComment["userPointer"] = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "_User", objectId: "nnnnnnnnn")
    myComment["imagePointer"] = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Objects", objectId: "nnnnnnnnn")

    let query = PFQuery(className:"Objects")
    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "tJP0kskNxQ")
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            for object in objects! {
                print(object)
                             var relation = object.relation(forKey: "comments")
                relation.add(myComment)

                relation.saveInBackground(block: { (success:Bool, error:Error?) -> Void in
                    if (success) {
                        print("Saved relation")
                        // The post has been added to the user's likes relation.
                    } else {
                        print(error)
                        // There was a problem, check error.description
                    }


                })
             }
        }
   }

    // This will save both myPost and myComment
    myComment.saveInBackground()

}
```

AND

```
let object = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Objects", objectId: "nnnnnnnnn")


   var relation = object.relationForKey("comment")
relation.addObject(myComment)
m.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if (success) {
    // The post has been added to the user's likes relation.
  } else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
  }
}
```

The comment saves with the pointers correctly HOWEVER the relation does not.

All tutorials I can can find are related to saving relations to a User however this is not what I want.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there an error in any of the queries? What output are you getting in the console? Does it find the relation?

Comment: thanks @hhanesand .....it wasn't showing any outputs in the console or logs. I've just solved! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.....turns out the fix is to put

```
var relation = object.relationForKey("comment")
relation.addObject(myComment)
```

inside the `saveInBackGround` block!